# Special types of Kamma Vipaka

Tags: karma

According to Buddhism the same good or bad deed has different results depending on who you are and the person being affected by your action, a few examples:
Giving food to a Buddha x Giving food to an ordinary person.
Lying and cheating if you are a monk x if you are a lay person.
Killing your parents x Killing ordinary people.

Ok, it does make sense, but the question is: Is there a simple logic behind it? Depending on the impact in the world per haps?! And what kind of force understands that you are doing the good/bad deed against a different (not ordinary) being?

Answer (score 2):

The karma is a product of

- The mind of the person doing the action
- The mind of the person subjected to the action

If the person who is subjected to the result of the action has a pure mind then the results are applied may it be good or bad.

If I give to a Buddha (very pure mind) with great piety the results would be great. If I do the same for a animal the results will not be that great since the results are not "amplified" due to a lower state of mind the animal has.

The Buddha has made great sacrifice to create the Sasana. So if we do something in line with the Buddha's will and intentions then the results would very much greater than any other action. Similarly if we go against it.